# Ruby regex section to match multiline

Tags: ruby, regex

So this is my code

`convert = contents.gsub(/\\s1(.*?)(\n\\r.*?)?\n((?s)\\ms3(.*?)\\p)/, 'replacement code')`

in the first bit: `\\s1(.*?)(\n\\r.*?)?\n`i only want it to match a newline when i tell it there's one there. But when searching for `\\ms3(.*?)\\p` i want it to pick up any newlines that are there. Unfortunately it looks like Ruby doesn't support this `(?s)`prefix. Is there any way of doing this?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `\n\\r`? Normally that's `\n\r`, or are you looking for literal backslash-r? Do you have an example of the sorts of data you're matching against you could append to your question?

Comment: @tadman im searching for a literal backslash

Comment: the dotall modifier in ruby is `m` not `s`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah, thank you. that's worked, i thought regexp would be the same in all languages

Comment: And if you want to impress your friends you can write: `(?m:\\ms3(.*?)\\p)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)==>([\s\S]*?)
```

You can use this instead of `DOTALL` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert = contents.gsub(/\\s1(.*?)(\n\\r.*?)?\n((\n*)\\ms3(.*?)\\p)/, 'replacement code')
```

This will capture any(0+) newlines before "\ms3". If it's not what you meant, please, clarify what functionality do you expect from `(?s)`?